# Anyone aware of a .sql version of the Stack Exchange data dump?

Tags: support, data-dump

I got the latest data dump and wrote a PHP script to parse the XML, but the actual parsing is taking forever (the uncompressed `Posts.xml` is 10GB). In the interim, does anyone know of a *MySQL-ready* `.sql` file that can be imported directly into the database?

I googled but the only thing I found was an inactive torrent of a much older version of the data dump, when the data dump was only 250MB. Does anyone know of a new version?

P.S. If anyone can point me to an existing `.sql`, that would be great. If not, I'll probably upload one when parsing is done, if there's interest. But I'm only parsing the `Posts` table, as this is all I need.

Comment: Part of the reason that XML was chosen is because it is a universal format. Your particular request only works with MySQL; SE would have to make a specific file for each database system.

Comment: Are you using the correct type of parser here?  You should be using an event-based parser, not some of the other parser that try to load the entire document into memory.

Comment: @Robert Harvey I agree, XML is the best here. I'm not expecting SE to prepare a database-specific file for each database under the sun. That's a lot of work. I was thinking of a community effort to arrange this, as needed, especially for the Posts table. It would be sweet to search questions on the go when no internet connection is available. When I was downloading from clearbits, it said 44 downloaded this file. It's not a lot of people, but maybe half of them use MySQL. Would be nice if we could all save some time.

Comment: @Zoredache Yep, I'm using XMLReader which is the stream-based reader in PHP. I initially tried the other XML readers, but quickly dropped them when they kept crashing the script. I think the reason the script takes a long time is that it's also inserting into the database.

Comment: Disable indexe, queue up a thousand or so posts and do mass inserts.

Comment: In case you are unaware of it, there is the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) that you can run queries on.  Not quite as flexible as having a local copy, but it's pretty cool.

Comment: All I can say is... don't *ever* try using Python to parse the Stack Overflow XML files. (Unless you have, say, 24 GB of RAM.)

Comment: Heh, I have extra server resources. I could possibly host and generate monthly a ready-to-download database in 1 or 2 formats depending on how well the data compresses

Answer (score 3):

I have used this java code to good effect

https://github.com/kashyaprpuranik/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/XMLDumpImporter/src/XMLDumpImporter/Main.java

.. it runs pretty fast once set up (and you need to add the jdbc driver)

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did.  Create a script that reads the xml and outputs to a CSV file, and then use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to load the data into MySQL.  Doing inserts one at time will take ages.

Also, I wish the data dump was in CSV to begin with. It's far more universal a format than XML especially when importing into databases is a concern.  But I think we've been over that already here.